# how to get the mouse position in assembly

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86-16, dos, mouse-position

here is a part of my code, this should draw a pixel on the mouse position:

```
mov ax,3h       ;set interruption to getting the mouse pos
int 33h         ;after the interruption: cx=x, dx=y

mov ah, 0Ch     ;draw a pixel
;the x and y should already be in the registers cx and dx after the last interruption
mov al, 5       ;set color (to some kind of purple)
int 10h         ;the drawing should happen here, but for some reason nothing is drawn
```

btw, im using video mode int 10h/ah=0h/al=12h, which has a 640x480 resolution and 16 colors.

Comment: https://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_33-3.html

the mouse position is (regardless of video mode) always returned in a resolution of 640 by 200. other resolutions may have to scale the values

Answer (score 2):

You are geting the mouse cursor position correctly, it should work.
I wrote a sample program

```
plsHelp Program Format=COM
    MOV AX,0012h
    INT 10h      ; Set graphic videomode 640*480.
Repeat:
    MOV AX,0003h
    INT 33h      ; Get mouse position and button status.
    TEST BX,2    ; Mouse right-button pressed?
    JNZ End
    MOV AX,0C05h
    INT 10h      ; Draw a pixel at CX*DX.
    JMP Repeat
End:RET          ; Terminate program.
   EndProgram
```

When assembled by `euroasm.exe plsHelp.asm` and run as `plsHelp.com` in DosBox on my Windows, moving the mouse  leaves a magenta track as expected. Perhaps something is wrong with your environment.

Comment: I ran your program and at first it didnt work, then I added: 
mov ax, 0h
int 33h
mov ax, 1h
int 33h

before the Repeat lable, and it worked. so the problem was probably with my environment <3